# How to create a new CSV file and copy some of columns from old huge CSV file?

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm a beginner in C#.

I have a huge CSV files with thousands of data(Rows and Columns). With one filter I have created a list called `requiredheaders`. In this list I took only those header names which are required further.

So, based on this header list, I wanted to create a new CSV file and need to copy those header names and data, which CSV headers are available in `requiredheaders` list.

```cs
var requiredheaders = new [] { "Column B", "Column D" };
```

For example:
old csv

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEF | ABC | BBB | ABC |
| ABC | DEF | ABC | BBB |
| BBB | ABC | DEF | ABC |
| ABC | BBB | BBB | DEF |
| BBB | ABC | ABC | BBB |
| DEF | DEF | BBB | DEF |

New csv should be:

| Column B | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | ABC |
| DEF | BBB |
| ABC | ABC |
| BBB | DEF |
| ABC | BBB |
| DEF | DEF |

I used CsvHelper package and I tried this solution but my `requiredheaders` list is dynamic and it changes based on some filters.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Specify the paths to the old and new CSV files
        string oldCsvFilePath = "old_data.csv";
        string newCsvFilePath = "new_data.csv";

        // Create a StreamWriter for the new CSV file
        using (var newFileWriter = new StreamWriter(newCsvFilePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(newFileWriter, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            // Create a CsvReader for the old CSV file
            using (var oldFileReader = new StreamReader(oldCsvFilePath))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(oldFileReader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
            {
                // Read the records from the old file and write selected data to the new file
                while (csvReader.Read())
                {
                    var record = csvReader.GetRecord<NewClass>();
                    
                    if (record.SomeCondition) 
                    {
                        csv.WriteRecord(record);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public class NewClass
{
    // Define properties that match the columns in your CSV file
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Add more properties as needed
}
```

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/johnkerl/miller command line tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maintain some packages that should make this very easy: [Sylvan.Data.Csv and Sylvan.Data](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan). The Sylvan.Data.Csv package provides the CSV reader/writer, while the Sylvan.Data package provides the `Select` method, which offers a LINQ-like projection over DbDataReader, of which CsvDataReader is an extension.

Here is a complete C# program demonstrating how these libraries can be used to accomplish your goal. No need to define a strongly-typed class to represent your data, the `requiredHeaders` can be generated dynamically at runtime if needed.

```cs
using Sylvan.Data;
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;

string oldCsvFilePath = "old_data.csv";
string newCsvFilePath = "new_data.csv";
var requiredheaders = new string[] { "Column B", "Column D" };

using var reader = CsvDataReader.Create(oldCsvFilePath);
using var writer = CsvDataWriter.Create(newCsvFilePath);

writer.Write(reader.Select(requiredheaders));
```

Comment: I also didn't need a strongly typed class for `CsvHelper`, but I do like the simplicity of your answer and it appears to be faster.  For a million records, my answer was averaging about .8 seconds and yours was taking about .3 seconds.  I did notice that your answer uses the Unix line break "\n" vs the windows "\r\n", but I assume that is configurable.

Comment: Yes, line break is configurable. I default to the shorter version, since for a million records that would result in a megabyte smaller file, with no semantic difference in content. I only mentioned no need for a class, because his original approach was using one.

Comment: @DavidSpecht, I haven't programmed in C# in a long time, so I don't know for sure, but... if instead of `csvReader.GetField(header)` you could compute a list/array of indexes the required headers correspond to, and loop over that static list instead of dynamically calling `GetField(header)` (a million times the number of columns), would that improve your program's performance?

Comment: @ZachYoung I tried several different options and I was able to get it to about .7 seconds using `csvReader.GetField(headerIndex)`.  I think it is just that `Sylvan.Data.Csv` is generally about twice as fast as `CsvHelper`. https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers

Comment: @MarkPflug can we allow case sensitivity in requiredheaders list?

Comment: @brown Yes.
var opts = new CsvDataReaderOptions
{
    HeaderComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
};
var reader = CsvDataReader.Create(oldCsvFilePath, opts);

Comment: @MarkPflug I'm also using this package. It works very well for my requirement. Recently I changed some functionality, so now my CSV file is bigger. There are approx 7200 columns, but now I'm facing an issue and it shows me `CsvRecordTooLargeException`. In the new CSV file I want 6500 columns from old data.

Is there any possibility in Sylvan to I can handle this Exception?

Comment: @RoySmith Yes. You need to set CsvDataReaderOptions.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue. This allows the internal buffer to grow "unbounded".

Comment: @MarkPflug As per document I already used this option for the buffer. But, still I'm getting same error. I'm getting CsvRecordTooLargeException error after a few minutes.

Comment: @RoySmith It sounds like there might be an issue with your CSV file, as this should only happen if there were a 2gb record, which is possible in a valid CSV file, I suppose. If you there is a bug in my code please open an issue on github, linked in my answer and I can take a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply select the column values from the old file by using `csvReader.GetField(headerName)`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var data = @"Column A,Column B,Column C,Column D
DEF,ABC,BBB,ABC
ABC,DEF,ABC,BBB
BBB,ABC,DEF,ABC
ABC,BBB,BBB,DEF
BBB,ABC,ABC,BBB
DEF,DEF,BBB,DEF";
    var requiredHeaders = new string[] { "Column B", "Column D" };

    // Create a StreamWriter for the new CSV file
    // using (var newFileWriter = new StreamWriter(newCsvFilePath))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
    {
        // Create a CsvReader for the old CSV file
        using (var oldFileReader = new StringReader(data))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(oldFileReader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            // Write the new header
            foreach (var header in requiredHeaders)
            {
                csv.WriteField(header);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();

            // Read the old header
            csvReader.Read();
            csvReader.ReadHeader();
            
            // Read the records from the old file and write selected data to the new file
            while (csvReader.Read())
            {
                foreach (var header in requiredHeaders)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(csvReader.GetField(header));
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZachYoung, The problem is, I can get an array of the record from `csvReader.Parser.Record`, but the notes say, "It is much more efficient to only get the fields you need. If you need all the fields use this".  I tried `csvReader.Parser.Record[columnNumber]` and it was about .05 seconds faster.  What was slightly faster than that was to use `csv.GetField(columnNumber)`.  That brought me to about .7 seconds instead of .8 seconds for the million records.